# What is the best way to change all letters in a word to one character?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-studio

I have an array of strings in my program.. I wanted to change each letter of the words to an 'x' or '*' or anything to make them hidden without losing the number of letters.

example:

```
String[] words = new String[] {
"random", "words", "are", "in", "this", "array"
}
```

I want to display them like this

```
random words are in this array
```

to

```
XXXXXX XXXX XXX XX XXXX XXXXX
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `replaceAll` method of the `String` class, [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: apparently I am not! smh on me! thank you anyways! I'll keep it in mind from now on!

Answer (score 6):

Use `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) :

```
yourString.replaceAll("\\S", "X");
```

Replace **non-whitespace** characters with **uppercase X** .

Modify the regex according to your needs, for example:

> all characters that aren't a space (as in ascii 32)

The regex would be `^[ ]`.

Helpful [resource for regex testing](https://www.regex101.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Arrays.stream` to get a `Stream` and then `map` each line with a regular expression. The pattern `\\S` matches any non-whitespace character, and you can use `Collectors.joining` to assemble the line. Like,

```
String[] words = { "random", "words", "are", "in", "this", "array" };
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(words).map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\S", "X"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Which outputs

```
XXXXXX XXXXX XXX XX XXXX XXXXX
```